# Get Stuck When Trying to Read Matrix from External File in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to read this file:

```
  1|2|3|4|5|81||
  6|7|8|9|10|91||
  11|12|13|14|15|92||
  16|17|18|19|20|93||end
```

and store them as a 2D array with delimiter `|`. This is my approach

```
   public  void setMatrixFromFile(FileReader fIn) throws FileNotFoundException{

         int row, col;
         Matrix = new double[HIGHEST_INDEX+1][HIGHEST_INDEX+1];
         Scanner scanFile;
         scanFile = new Scanner(fIn).useDelimiter("|");
         row = LOWEST_INDEX + 1;
         col = 0;
         while (row <= HIGHEST_INDEX && (scanFile.hasNext()) && 
                 (!scanFile.next().matches("(.*)end(.*)"))){
               col = LOWEST_INDEX + 1;
               while (col <= HIGHEST_INDEX && scanFile.hasNext() && 
                       (!scanFile.next().matches("(.*)||(.*)"))){
                        if (scanFile.hasNextDouble() || scanFile.hasNextInt()){
                            this.setElMatrix(row, col, scanFile.nextDouble());
                            col++;
                        }
               }
               if (scanFile.hasNext()){
                   scanFile.next();
               }
               row++;
         }
         this.setColEff(col);
         this.setRowEff(row-1);
     }
```

`setElMatrix` as it name suggests only has this

```
     public void setElMatrix(int i, int j, double elMatrix)  
     {
     Matrix[i][j] = elMatrix; // i = row index, j = column index
     }
```

Well, `HIGHEST_INDEX` has set to `100` and `LOWEST_INDEX` has set to `0`. Then, I have following code to (manually) test the above code.

```
     import java.util.*;
     import java.io.*;

     public class TestMatriks
     {
     public static void main (String []args) throws FileNotFoundException{
            Matriks mTest1 = new Matriks();
            FileReader fin = new FileReader("testcase.txt");
            mTest1.setMatrixFromFile(fin);
            mTest1.outMatrix();

            }
     }
```

`outMatrix` is used to output the 2d array into monitor and expected output is

```
   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 81.0
   6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 91.0
   11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 92.0
   16.0 17.0 18.0 19.0 20.0 93.0
```

When the above code is executed, it produces this:

```
   0.0
   0.0
```

I still couldn't figure what's wrong with my code. Yes, I've read as many references as I could, asking my friends, but that couldn't help.

Second question: If I move the file into directory that not the same as the directory which I've put in the source code, how can I modify the above code? I want to put the whole project (and the file) into a portable storage, and put the input file into a separated folder from the code.

Edit:

More details on `Matrix` class:

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.io.*;

 public class Matriks
 {
 private static final int ROW_SIZE = 101;  
 private static final int COLUMN_SIZE = 101;  
 private static final double Val_Undef = -999999999999999.999;  //unused 
 private static final int LOWEST_INDEX = 0;  
 private static final int HIGHEST_INDEX =100; 
 private static final int IDX_UNDEF = -9999; 
 private double[][] Matrix;
 private int rowEff;
 private int colEff;

 //methods
```

}

Sorry for my poor english, and sorry if my questions are too obvious. I'm still at beginner level in java.

Comment: Could you show Matrix class?

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity the code itself is a method of bigger Matrix class, and the whole matrix class would be too long to be posted. Thanks, i will edit the post to include its attribute

Answer (score 1):

Few observations:

1. index should start with 0. below +1 is not required.
   row = LOWEST_INDEX + 1; 
   col = LOWEST_INDEX + 1;
2. Since you tokenize using | delimiter, you will not be able to catch || in the below regex match.
   !scanFile.next().matches("(.*)||(.*)")
3. Put some System.out logs in middle of the code and see the data return by scanner.